# asynchronous dependent futures with priorities in R

Tags: r, promise, future

Here is a typical analysis workflow.

[image: Example Analysis Work Flow]

Running this sequentially looks like:

```
## some simple functions to mimic longer running models
m1 <- \() {
  Sys.sleep(4*15)
  "model 1 results"
}

m2 <- \() {
  Sys.sleep(3*15)
  "model 2 results"
}

m3 <- \() {
  Sys.sleep(2*15)
  "model 3 results"
}

process <- \(text) {
  Sys.sleep(0.5 * 10)
  sprintf("processed %s", text)
}

###### Approach 1 ~155.2 seconds --- sequential ######
start <- proc.time()

## model 1
m1res <- m1()
p1res <- process(m1res)
cat(p1res, fill = TRUE)

## model 2
m2res <- m2()
p2res <- process(m2res)
cat(p2res, fill = TRUE)

## model 3
m3res <- m3()
p3res <- process(m3res)
cat(p3res, fill = TRUE)

stop <- proc.time()

## total run time
stop - start
```

and takes ~155.2 seconds. Using the `future` package, we can speed that up. Assuming 2 CPUs.

```
###### Approach 2 ~102.7 seconds --- models not blocked but not optimal run ######
## load future package and setup a multisession with 2 workers
library(future)
plan("multisession", workers = 2)


start <- proc.time()

## fit models 
p1res <- future({
  model1 <- m1()
  process(model1)
})
p2res <- future({
  model2 <- m2()
  process(model2)
})
p3res <- future({
  model3 <- m3()
  process(model3)
})

## present results
cat(value(p1res), fill = TRUE)
cat(value(p2res), fill = TRUE)
cat(value(p3res), fill = TRUE)

stop <- proc.time()

## total run time
stop - start
```

Now we are down to ~102.7 seconds, but this is still not optimal. What ideally would happen is:

- CPU 1: runs model 1, processes model 1, processes model 2
- CPU 2: runs model 2, runs model 3, processes model 3

```
###### Approach 3 ~82.7 seconds --- models not blocked but not optimal run ######
start <- proc.time()

## fit models 
m1res %<-% m1()
m2res %<-% m2()
m3res %<-% m3()

## grab results
p1res %<-% process(m1res)
p2res %<-% process(m2res)
p3res %<-% process(m3res)

## present results
cat(p1res, fill = TRUE)
cat(p2res, fill = TRUE)
cat(p3res, fill = TRUE)

stop <- proc.time()

## total run time
stop - start
```

We can get that, which now only takes about 82.7 seconds. However, the code is no longer organized in a very clear way. Everything for Analysis 1 is not together anymore.

Is it possible to write the code like Approach 1, keeping the models and post processing, etc. together, while having `R` run it like the 3rd approach?  Pseudo code would look like:

```
m1res <- future({
  m1()
}, priority = 1)

p1res <- future({
  process(m1res)
}, priority = 2, dependson = "m1res")

m2res <- future({
  m2()
}, priority = 1)

p2res <- future({
  process(m2res)
}, priority = 2, dependson = "m2res")
```

Essentially some sort of job/task scheduler, where it is possible to build dependencies in the futures and a priority list, so that:

(1) tasks are run greedily as available, as long as the dependency has already been resolved
(2) if multiple tasks are available, high priority tasks are run preferentially over lower priority tasks.

I tried playing with the `lazy = TRUE` option in `future` to see if I could basically queue things up, but you cannot use an unresolved future in another future when using multisession.

Comment: Have you considered putting each "task" into a separate script and using a dedicated tool like Make or [DVC](https://dvc.org/) to run them? DVC might be an especially good option because of how long these computations take to run. You want to make sure the results get saved somewhere safe!

Comment: @shadowtalker hmm I had not thought of that, but I will. I'm terrible with `make` but can learn. Will look at DVC. Thanks!